# How do I express the weather being helpful to my plans?

Tags: idiom-requests

I know there's the expression "weather permitting", but I want to use it like this:

> I plan to go on a bike ride tomorrow, so let's hope the weather ____!

Is there a word more idiomatic than "permits" for this context?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want a single word that fits your given blank? Or do you want to use "weather permitting"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I most often hear (and say) [*let's hope the weather **cooperates***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22let%27s%20hope%20the%20weather%20cooperates%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS696US697&oq=%22let%27s%20hope%20the%20weather%20cooperates%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.5079j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) in this context. It's a slight bit of anthropomorphism, as if "the weather" is a capricious being who might or might not agree to help out with our plans. It's nicely general, so it can apply equally to hoping for cool, dry weather for a bike ride or very hot weather for a day at the beach or lots of snowfall for a ski trip.

The other common way of doing this is to reference the *current* weather; so if it's already fair the day before your planned expedition, you could say something like *let's hope the weather **stays nice***, but if it's raining today you would say something like *let's hope the weather **improves***.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard "suits" used in this case. Sentence structure could be altered to use adjectives of suitable, such as "fitting."

Answer (score 1):

To fit your sentence as it is:

> I plan to go on a bike ride tomorrow, so let's hope the weather **holds**!

Ref: [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hold+out)

> 2. a. To maintain a desired or accustomed position or condition:
>      *hopes the weather will hold.*

Answer (score 0):

"I plan to go on a bike ride tomorrow, so let's hope the weather ***is ideal***." You'll often here on weather reports the meteorologist saying, "Ideal weather tomorrow" or "Ideal conditions for..."

Answer (score -1):

Simply this way:

> I plan to go on a bike ride tomorrow, **weather permitting**.

Ref: [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/weather-permitting)

> used for saying that something will happen if bad weather does not prevent it
>   *The game starts at 11 o’clock, weather permitting.*